# Is there a way to list the Shared Mailboxes of a user using Outlook Rest API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Is there a way to list the Shared Mailbox a user has access to using Outlook Web API or Graph API?

Say user **user@whatnot.com** has access to shared mailbox **share1@whatnot.com** and **share2@whatnot.com**, I would like to get **share1@whatnot.com** and **share2@whatnot.com**.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can get access to Shared mailboxes using Microsoft Graph API.

You can use this requesst to do this

```
GET users/{userId | userPrincipalName}/mailfolders('Inbox')/messages
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.